# How to change line style on custom variable that plots previous day high/low lines? Pine script

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5

I am creating an indicator the charts previous day high and low lines. I have written the code and  the data plots as it should, but I am unable to change the line style. It is defaulting to a dotted line, but I want a solid line. I know I am using the plot function correctly and in defining the line style I am using the correct input. The only thing I can think of that I am defining my own variable so it won't allow me to change the line style. Please help!

```
//Yesterday high and low
bool afterHours = hour < 20 and hour >= 16 or hour == 20 and minute <= 00
bool preHours = hour < 9 and minute <= 30 or hour >= 4 or hour == 4
bool marketHours = hour > 9 and minute >= 30 and hour < 16 and minute <= 00

//Current High And Low
currentdayhigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high[0])
currentdaylow = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low[0])

//Yesterday high and low
previousdayhigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high[1])
previousdaylow = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low[1])

if preHours
    previousdayhigh := currentdayhigh
    previousdaylow := currentdaylow
       
if marketHours
    previousdayhigh := previousdayhigh
    previousdaylow := previousdaylow
    
if afterHours
    previousdayhigh := currentdayhigh
    previousdaylow := currentdaylow

plot(previousdayhigh, style=plot.style_line, title='Yesterday\'s high', color=color.new(#ffdf00, 0), linewidth=1, trackprice=true, offset=k)
pdh = label.new(x=time + td, y=previousdayhigh, text='PREVIOUS HIGH', xloc=xloc.bar_time, style=label.style_none, textcolor=#ffdf00, size=size.small, textalign=text.align_right)
label.delete(pdh[1])

plot(previousdaylow, style=plot.style_line, title='Yesterday\'s low', color=color.new(#ffdf00, 0), linewidth=1, trackprice=true, offset=k)
pdl = label.new(x=time + td, y=previousdaylow, text='PREVIOUS LOW', xloc=xloc.bar_time, style=label.style_none, textcolor=#ffdf00, size=size.small, textalign=text.align_right)
label.delete(pdl[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the 'trackprice' line then you cannot change this line style. Dotted only

Comment: I appreciate that. Is there a way to rewrite this so it does update the line with every new bar during these specific times and not have it be dotted?